# Intent for activity being ignored

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two Android applications - A and B.

Application B has two Activities, its Launcher Activity which we'll call Activity 1,  and another we'll call Activity 2.

Application A needs to call both Application B's activities multiple times each in arbitrary sequence.

What I've found though is that if I call Activity 2 (from Application A) then later call Activity 1 - this works.

What doesn't work is when I need to call Activity 2  anytime AFTER I've called Activity 1.

When I do this I always get Activity 1 regardless.

Looking at the logs I can see that the ActivityManager is receiving an intent with the correct ComponentName for Activity 2 that I've set in my code in Application A - yet still it still resolves to Activity 1.

The only thing that has worked is when I call finish() in the onPause() method for Activity 1.  If I do this - Application A can call both Application B's activities without issue.

This is not a good solution generally but it is definitely not a solution for me as I'm trying to define an integration pattern with Application A  that pre-existing apps (App B in this case) can follow.

Is there any way I can alter this result by the way I call Application B's activities from Application A (as opposed to modifying the activity configuration in Application B).

At the moment I call both Activity 1 and Activity 2 by their ComponentName like so:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
intent.setComponent(name);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

The only difference is that for the non-launcher activity (Activity 2)  I am using action VIEW and category DEFAULT (vs MAIN and LAUNCHER as per above).

Obviously Activity 2 also needs an intent filter matching that combination - but assuming it does..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Did you already have a look at the different `Activity` attibutes? `android:finishOnTaskLaunch` seems to me as if it could be of help.

See a full list at the [Developers Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).